# What is the difference between using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier and performseguewithidentifier?

Tags: ios, swift, oop

Both methods allow me to present a new view controller (one by calling presentviewcontroller), so I don't understand the difference between the two and when I should use them.

Comment: instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier does what its name says; it instantiates a view controller, nothing more. It does *not* present a view controller.

Comment: @rdelmar I've addressed your comment to clarify for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*performSegueWithIdentifer* and *instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier* both are used to move from one viewController to another viewController.
   But there is so much differences....

1. The identifier of the 1st case defines a segue like push, modal, custom etc which are used to perform a specific type of transition from one VC to another VC. 
   eg.

   ```
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: self);`
   ```

   where "push" is an identifier of a push segue.

   The identifier of the 2nd case defines a VC like myViewController, myTableViewController, myNavigationController etc. 2nd function is used to go to the specific VC ( with identifier.) from a VC in the storyBoard.
   eg.

   ```
   var vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameView") as GameViewController; 
   self.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil) ;
   ```

   where "GameView" is the identifier of GameViewController.
   Here a instance of GameViewController is created and then the function *presentViewController* is called to go to the instantiated vc.
2. For the 1st case with the help of segue identifier u can pass one are more values of variables to the next VC.
   eg.

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) 
   {
       if (segue.identifier == "push") 
       {
           let game = segue.destinationViewController as GameViewController
           game.value = self.myvalue // *value* is an Int variable of GameViewController class and *myvalue* is an Int variable of recent VC class.
       }
   }
   ```

   This funcion is also called when self.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: self); is called to pass the value to  GameViewController.

   But in 2nd case it possible directly like,

   ```
   var vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameView") as GameViewController; 
   vc.value = self.myvalue;
   self.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil) ;
   ```

Answer (score 9):

They both reference storyboard related identifiers. The main difference is one (`performSegueWithIdentifer`) instantiates an object based on a segue's end (where the segue points to), while the other (`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`) instantiates a unique VC based on the VC's identifier (not the segue).

You can have multiple segue's with the same identifier in different places in the storyboard, while VC's in a storyboard cannot have the same identifier.

Comment: Since they do roughly the same thing, when would one be preferred over the other? Also which one is used most in projects where the layouts are done programmatically? I guess you would use `performSegueWithIdentifer` when you want specific transition types for UX since  `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is only a vanilla transition right?

Comment: @tymac Generally I think most would use `performSegueWithIdentifer` as the segue defines flow. `instantiate...` makes the storyboard layout more undefined (as you are defining transitions in code). If layouts are done programmatically, you wouldn't use either generally. Just create a class instance and present it: e.g. `let vc = FooVC()` ... `self.present(vc)`