# Advantages of using segues

Tags: ios, swift

I created new View Controller in storyboard. Now I want it to appear on screen. All books, tutorials, courses tell me that I should use segues to transfer data between controllers. Why?

Usually I do this:

```
let newViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newViewController") as NewViewController
self.presentViewController(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

That way seems to me more clear and useful. I can create new scene with Interface Builder, name it with identifier and take it from storyboard whenever I want.

What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: In my opinion, there's nothing wrong with it.  Some people prefer configuration and others prefer code.  (On the other hand, I don't like transferring data between controllers at all.  I'd rather have an independent data model.)

Comment: To understand the difference between them in details, refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009400/what-is-the-difference-between-using-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier-and

Comment: Segues enables you to move more UI setup to Interface Builder, that is reduce manual code and the possibility of error. In this case there is almost no difference though. It's not a good idea to put all controllers into one storyboard either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach. Just as there's nothing wrong with dropping UIViewController completely and handling the view hierarchy on the UIWindow yourself.

`UIStoryboardSegue` is there as a tool for you to use if you want to. It is useful as it allows you to transition between view controllers with little to no code if necessary.

For instance, in an app I have (just a proof of concept) I have a `UIViewController` with several buttons that acts as a menu and I can transition to other `UIViewControllers` through each button. But there is no subclass with code in. It is entirely done in Interface Builder.

What it adds for storyboards is a level of clarity of what flows where. You know that view controller A transitions to view controller B because there's an arrow on the screen that tells you this.

Comment: Ok, that sounds fine. But how do I use segue when I don't have a sender actually? For example, I work with camera, and want view controllers changing after "Use Photo" pressed. I cannot drag segue in Interface Builder!

Comment: @SergeyGamayunov in that specific case the camera should be mod ally presented and the delegate will dismiss it before it segues to another view controller. But in the case where you don't have an item in the story board to argue from/to then just use the other way. You can mix and match however you wish.

Answer (score 2):

> This type of connection is known as a segue and represents a
>   transition from one screen to another. The The storyboard connections
>   you’ve seen so far were relationships and they described one view
>   controller containing another. A segue, on the other hand, changes
>   what is on the screen. Segues are triggered by taps on buttons, table
>   view cells, gestures, and so on.

It is storyboard feather used to pass data back and fourth by segue and unwind segue by destinationViewController and sourceViewController.identifier property used to compare different screens. check for more reference [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50310/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2).

Ex.Pass data to next screen.

```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            destViewController.recipeName = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }
```

Ex.Pass data back screen,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [segue sourceViewController];
    [settingsViewController setAddressString:[self addressString]];
    NSLog(@"Settings address string of SettingsViewController to: %@", [self addressString]);
    settingsViewController.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when you use segues - your storyboard become more readable. Everyone will see, that from this controller I can navigate to this one and from this to this one. It is a main feature of segues. From code it will be much more harder to understand with what controllers some controller is connected. (In other way there is no need to use storyboards, you can instantiate controllers from nib files)

Also it do not require writing extra code if it is connected to some action UI (button, gesture, cell, etc.).

Even when you need to call "performSegue:" method it is better than instantiating controller. In this case, you can change segues types without changing the code, what is not possible with instantiation.

There is a lot of thinks that we can discuss about, but the general idea is that you incapsulate the way you are navigating in project, and it help you to decrease dependencies and understand navigation in project from storyboard.