# Is it better practice to performSegueWithIdentifier or presentViewController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

If I am using storyboards, is it better practice to create a segue and use performSegueWithIdentifier or just use presentViewController to move the user from one View Controller to the next.

For this example, let's assume we are using Swift 5 and I have 2 view controllers: a TableView of Contacts on MainViewController and the details of that Contact on DetailViewController.

In my code, I am using presentViewController, but as I am new to iOS development, I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: If you are using two ***storyboards*** you have to use `presentViewController`, if you are using one storyboard containing two view controllers it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @vadian, even with two **storyboards** you can drag out a *Storyboard Reference* object to stand in for the VC in the second storyboard and use a normal segue.

Comment: @vacawama Really? Good to know, you live and learn. 

Comment: @vadian, that's why we're all here.  It's impossible to know everything especially when Apple keeps changing things. ;-)

Comment: It’s more a personal decision I think, from my experience I prefer not to use segues at all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34790697/1630618

Comment: OP please show your actual code and actual storyboard details. No point talking in generalities.

Comment: Update: 1 storyboard, 2 view controllers. Sorry for the confusion in the example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume for purposes of illustration that the situation in the storyboard is as follows:

```
ViewController1
    |----> modal segue "toVC2" emanating from ViewController1
        |----> ViewController2, identifier "VC2"
```

Then in ViewController1 code there is absolutely no functional or effective difference between these two things:

- Call `performSegue` with identifier `"toVC2"`
- Call `instantiateViewController` on the storyboard with identifier `"VC2"` and call `present`

Having said that, I will make a case for each way being "better" than the other.

#### Why the segue might be better

The segue in my example doesn't look much better because we still have to use code to call `performSegue`. However, suppose that the segue emanates not from the view controller but from a *button* in the view controller's view. That is an *action* segue and now the segue will be performed *automatically* when the user taps our button, with *no code* needed to perform it. You don't even need to know the identifier. (String identifiers are a great way to make a mistake.)

#### Why `instantiate` and `present` might be better

There is something very horrible about segues, whether it's an action segue or a manually triggered segue with `performSegue` — namely, when (as so often happens) you want to pass data from the first view controller to the second. If you use a segue, you must do the data-passing in an implementation of `prepare(for:sender:)`. This is very messy because you have to check the segue identifier and cast the destination to the correct class. Moreover, if there is more than one segue, `prepare` becomes a messy bottleneck. And if we also called `performSegue`, we are operating in two different places — the method where we called `performSegue`, and the separate implementation of `prepare`.

By contrast, if we call `instantiateViewController`, what comes back to us is the view controller instance itself. We still have to cast, but now we can pass the data right then and there, without "waiting" for `prepare` and without passing through a bottleneck. Thus this is a far more legible and encapsulated way of proceeding.

Also, this may seem obvious, but a nice thing about saying `present` is that this tells us right there in the code what the transition *is*. If you just use a segue identifier, the fact that this is a modal segue is hidden off in the storyboard.

#### Which do I prefer?

Neither. I prefer not to use storyboards at all for presented view controllers if I can help it. I use a view controller and eponymous nib. That way, I simply instantiate the view controller itself and pass it the data and `present` it, with no need to cast and no need for any identifiers.

#### So am I saying that storyboards are no good at all?

No. Storyboards have the virtue of mapping out the scene structure of your app, especially if you do use segues. If you are *not* going to use a segue to a view controller, however, then I don't really see the point of keeping that view controller in a storyboard in the first place. The eponymous nib mechanism is clearer and cleaner. Moreover, I regard the `prepare(for:sender:)` mechanism as a near-fatal flaw in the entire storyboard architecture; a huge majority of mistakes shown on Stack Overflow are a consequence of this flaw.

[**EDIT** Note that a lot of my objections to segues will fall away in iOS 13, where the source view controller will be able to use code to call an initializer of the destination view controller.]

Comment: Matt, why do you view `prepare(for:sender:)` as a flaw?

Comment: @matt, Thanks. That was very helpful. When I started this app, I started with segues and multiple VCs. I had about 5 VCs including a menu. The app is now expanding and I was wondering how I would handle 20 VCs. But now I have found that using 1 VC for the "details" scene will be better with various xibs based on what was selected in the menu/navigation.

Comment: Matt, I confess, I only scanned your answer. I went back and read the section on the evils of `prepare(for:sender:)`. One thing I do to handle that more cleanly is to use a switch statement on the **class** of the destination view controller: `switch segue.destination {`  then `case let detailViewController as DetailViewController: <code>`... `case let otherVC as OtherVC: <code>`. That uses the class of the destiniation to select the block of code to execute, casts the destination to the desired type in the same expression, and breaks out the different blocks of code into cases.

Comment: If you wanted to get fancier, you could probably build a dictionary with the type of the destination VC as the key and a closure as the value and put setup with the code that triggers the segue.

Comment: Another reason I don't really like segues is that you have to have a different segue for every source/destination link you need, and with a complex arrangement of view controllers you can wind up with the segue links turning into a mess of cobwebs.

Comment: @DuncanC Instead of writing an extended essay in the form of multiple comments, please feel free to add your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them do the same thing, But i usually use Present so when i want to change the behaviour for example, make the button open another VC, i just change the identifier, i don't have to remove the segue and create a new one.
Also many segues would make your storyboard look spaghetti